# Bash: Waiting on a background python process

Tags: python, linux, bash, macos, shell

I'm trying to:

1. launch a background process (a python script)
2. run some bash commands
3. Then send control-C to shut down the background process once the foreground tasks are finished

Minimal example of the what I've tried - Python `test.py`:

```
import sys

try:
    print("Running")
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Escape!")
```

Bash `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 ./test.py &
pid=$!

# ... do something here ...
sleep 2

# Send an interrupt to the background process
# and wait for it to finish cleanly
echo "Shutdown"
kill -SIGINT $pid
wait

result=$?
echo $result
exit $result
```

But the bash script seems to be hanging on the wait and the SIGINT signal is not being sent to the python process.

I'm using Mac OS X, and am looking for a solution that works for bash on linux + mac.

**Edit:** Bash was sending interrupts but Python was not capturing them when being run as a background job. Fixed by adding the following to the Python script:

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.default_int_handler)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ruslan - I was able to resolve my issue by re-adding the signal handler in python.

Answer (score 0):

The point is `SIGINT` is used to terminate foreground process. You should directly use `kill $pid` to terminate background process.

BTW, `kill $pid` is equal to `kill -15 $pid` or `kill -SIGTERM $pid`.

## Update

You can use `signal` module to deal with this situation.

```
import signal
import sys
def handle(signum, frame):
    sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle)
print("Running")
while True:
    pass
```

Comment: I want to send an interrupt (equivalent to pressing control-C) which I can catch in python to shutdown cleanly. `SIGTERM` just terminates the background process.

Comment: OK, I got your point, and I will update my answer.